# Does LSTM model retains previous training information?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, training-data

I wanted to fit the LSTM model on new data set in a loop so I have implemented it like this

```
#................................define model...........................
model =Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input,n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()

for k, v in enumerate(nse.get_fno_lot_sizes()):
    if v not in ('^NSEI','NIFTYMIDCAP150.NS','NIFTY_FIN_SERVICE.NS','^NSEBANK'):
        #-----------Create Training--------------------

        df = pd.read_csv('data\\'+ v+ ".csv", index_col = 0)

        train = df[['close']].iloc[:int(len(df)*0.8)]
        scaler = MinMaxScaler()
        scaler.fit(train)
        scaled_train = scaler.transform(train)
         
        #------------------------------------------------------
        generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train,scaled_train,length=n_input, batch_size=1)

        #-----------------------------------------------------
        #fit model
        model.fit(generator,epochs=10)
```

but I do not see much change in loss when it is being trained on new data in the loop.

So should the model definition be inside the for loop? Or does the model retains the information that it has learned during training on previous data and starts from there when it is being trained on new data?

The output looks like this, as you can see for the first iteration there is improvement in loss, but in the subsequent iteration even though loss is very less but there is no improvement. So I am thinking does the model starts with what it learned on previous data?

```
ABB
Epoch 1/10
340/340 [==============================] - 5s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0110
Epoch 2/10
340/340 [==============================] - 4s 11ms/step - loss: 0.0036
Epoch 3/10
340/340 [==============================] - 5s 14ms/step - loss: 0.0030
Epoch 4/10
340/340 [==============================] - 5s 15ms/step - loss: 0.0026
Epoch 5/10
340/340 [==============================] - 5s 15ms/step - loss: 0.0023
Epoch 6/10
340/340 [==============================] - 4s 11ms/step - loss: 0.0021
Epoch 7/10
340/340 [==============================] - 3s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0021
Epoch 8/10
340/340 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.0018
Epoch 9/10
340/340 [==============================] - 6s 18ms/step - loss: 0.0019
Epoch 10/10
340/340 [==============================] - 4s 13ms/step - loss: 0.0016
2095.0888767714823
COFORGE
Epoch 1/10
341/341 [==============================] - 5s 15ms/step - loss: 5.6781e-04
Epoch 2/10
341/341 [==============================] - 5s 15ms/step - loss: 7.1337e-04
Epoch 3/10
341/341 [==============================] - 3s 9ms/step - loss: 8.9877e-04
Epoch 4/10
341/341 [==============================] - 4s 10ms/step - loss: 6.3606e-04
Epoch 5/10
341/341 [==============================] - 5s 14ms/step - loss: 6.4658e-04
Epoch 6/10
341/341 [==============================] - 6s 17ms/step - loss: 5.7911e-04
Epoch 7/10
341/341 [==============================] - 4s 13ms/step - loss: 5.4928e-04
Epoch 8/10
341/341 [==============================] - 4s 11ms/step - loss: 5.8189e-04
Epoch 9/10
341/341 [==============================] - 5s 14ms/step - loss: 5.8669e-04
Epoch 10/10
341/341 [==============================] - 5s 15ms/step - loss: 5.9930e-04
```

Comment: @GoldenLion batch size for what? batch size is already defined in timeseriesgenerator function. The for loop is get new data and again train the model on it.

Comment: @GoldenLion can you explain the reasoning behind your answer? I am not able to understand why we need that when I already have the TimeSeriesGenerator function

Comment: your suppose to use model.fit_generator with TimeSeriesGenerator https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-the-timeseriesgenerator-for-time-series-forecasting-in-keras/#:~:text=Keras%20provides%20the%20TimeseriesGenerator%20that,into%20a%20supervised%20learning%20problem.

Comment: @GoldenLion  For TensorFlow 2.2+ users, just use the .fit method for your projects. The .fit_generator method will be deprecated in future releases of TensorFlow as the .fit method can automatically detect if the input data is an array or a generator.

Comment: thanks for the information.  I was referencing code from deep learning with python

Comment: @GoldenLion if I am using loop to train the model do I have to define the model in the loop or outside it?

Answer (score 0):

@Stupid_Intern, it looks like at each iteration you train the model on new data, but using the fit from previous iterations as a starting point (correct me if I am wrong).

This should decrease the amount of time it takes for the model to get to a good fit, but it will not make the model fit well to all of the data, only the data at hand that you are using to fit it.

What you want is to fit the model to all of the data. Or if you want to keep the loop and updating structure you can fit the model to all of the cumulative data each time.